# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php

Проблема такая при регистрации пишет:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
> fetch() on a non-object in
> /var/www/u0009646/data/www/bmcraft.ru/system/db.class.php
> on line 180

Код:

```
public function fetch($sql)
{
    $query = $this->pdo->query($sql);
    $fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $fetch;
}
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код, для этого выделите код и нажмите {} в редакторе

Comment: Проверьте, является ли $this->pdo объектом класса PDO:

    var_dump($this->pdo instanceof PDO);

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что строка *$this->pdo->query($sql);* возвращает не объект, а после этого вы пытаетесь вызывать на нем метод fetch(). Вероятно, это связано с тем, что вы передаете неверный запрос в эту функцию и pdo->query() возвращает false. Необходимо добавить проверку для такой ситуации и разобраться почему не проходит запрос.